# Is there a way to convert an observable collection to regular collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I've got a test collection setup as :

```
ObservableCollection<Person> MyselectedPeople = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       FillData();
    }

public void FillData()
    {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.NameFirst = "John";
        p1.NameLast = "Doe";
        p1.Address = "123 Main Street";
        p1.City = "Wilmington";
        p1.DOBTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("04/12/1968").Date;
        p1.EyeColor = "Blue";
        p1.Height = "601";
        p1.HairColor = "BRN";

        MyselectedPeople.Add(p1);
    }
```

Once I have this collection built I would like to be able to convert the Observable Collection to the type List.

The reason behind this is my main project is receiving a generic list with data I have to convert it to an Observable collection for use in gridview, listboxes etc. Data is selected within the UI and then sent back to the originating assembly for further usage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the quickest way to do this is with LINQ.

```
 List<Person> personList= MySelectedPeople.ToList();
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following

```
var list = MyselectedPeople.ToList();
```

Make sure you have `System.Linq` as one of your using statements.

Answer (score 7):

This should do it...

```
List<Person> myList = MyselectedPeople.ToList<Person>();
```

Answer (score 6):

I just want to point out that aside from the obvious Linq extension method, List has always had an overload that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`

```
return new List<Person>(MyselectedPeople);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's odd that your back-end assembly is coded to only accept `List<T>`. That's very restrictive, and prevents you from doing useful things like passing an array, or an `ObservableCollection<T>`, or a `Collection<T>`, or a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, or the Keys or Values properties of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, or any of the myriad of other list-like things out there.

If possible, change your back-end assembly to accept an `IList<T>`. Then you can just pass in your `ObservableCollection<T>` as-is, without ever needing to copy its contents into a `List<T>`.

Comment: I've seen legacy libraries or 3rd party assemblies that were poorly designed far to often to find his problem odd.