# Custom (derived) List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, collections, derived-class

Feel free to load your guns and take aim, but I want to understand why you shouldn't do this.

I have created a custom class designed to replace any instances of List (which I use to update XML objects behind them):

```
public class ListwAddRemove<T> : List<T> {
    public event EventHandler<ListModifyEventArgs> OnAdd;
    public event EventHandler<ListModifyEventArgs> OnRemove;

    new public void Add(T o) {
        base.Add(o);

        if (OnAdd != null) {
            OnAdd(this, new ListModifyEventArgs(o));
        }
    }

    new public void Remove(T o) {
        base.Remove(o);

        if (OnRemove != null) {
            OnRemove(this, new ListModifyEventArgs(o));
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is whenever I add or remove an item from this list my bound events will fire and I can deal with the XML behind automatically.

This works like a charm, so far so good.

But how do I handle a conversion between object.ToList() and my derived version?

A lot of people are saying you should derive from Collection instead... why?

Comment: Have you heard about ObservableCollection ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167752/is-there-a-way-to-convert-an-observable-collection-to-a-list

Comment: I'm using Windows Forms .Net 3.5

Comment: Using the `new` modifier to hide members from the base class is never a good idea. If you really feel like deriving from `List<>`, give your methods some new names, such as `AddAndRaiseEvent` or similar. However, `List<>` class is not really designed for this use. There are other classes that offer more `virtual` members meant to be helpful when inheriting them.

Comment: @user1830285 ObservableCollection is still available in .Net 3.5 and can be used with Windows Forms, it's just a Collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interfaces. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279185/what-is-the-use-of-observablecollection-in-net for more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should derive from `Collection<T>` because it's designed to allow you to override `InsertItem`, and `RemoveItem` to add custom behavior such as what you're doing (also `SetItem`, to add custom behavior when changing an existing item).

It can therefore be used as an `IList<T>`, and any insertion/removal will automatically use the customisation.

In your case, anyone who casts to `IList<T>` or the base class `List<T>` will bypass your custom Add/Remove functionality.

`Collection<T>` also provides a constructor to wrap an existing list.  You can expose this from your derived class to wrap a list generated by `Enumerable<T>.ToList()`.

**UPDATE**

> Whats the syntax to expose the constructor please?

Very simple:

```
public class ListwAddRemove<T> : Collection<T>
{
    public ListwAddRemove<T>()
    {
    }

    public ListwAddRemove<T>(IList<T> list) : base(list)
    {
    }

    ... implementation of overrides for InsertItem, SetItem, RemoveItem ...
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
IList<SomeType> list = ....ToList();
ListwAddRemove<SomeType> myList = new ListwAddRemove<SomeType>(list);
```

Comment: Anyone who casts to the `IList<T>` interface will lose the new functionality, but so will anyone who casts to the base class `List<T>` (as in MartinStettner's answer).

Comment: "You can expose this from your derived class to wrap a list generated by"... Whats the syntax to expose the constructor please? I'm liking this implementation

Comment: Its ok got it:public ListwAddRemove(List<T> incomingList) : base(incomingList) { }

Answer (score 2):

For one,

```
void DoSomeAddingToList(List<int> list) {
  list.Add(1);
}

var list = new ListwAddRemove<int>();
DoSomeAddingToList(list);
```

will not trigger the events. That might lead to strange effect, especially if you're not the only one using the class.

`List<T>` defines a very specific behaviour for `Add` and `Remove` (since it's a concrete class), and users might rely on exactly this behaviour.

I think this is generally true for using a `new` modifier, so this language feature should be used with caution, especially on public methods.

As others have mentioned, *implementing* `IList<T>` (using delegation/aggregation) is probably the better choice.