# WPF save dataset to xml

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid, dataset

I have tried to read/save xml file to datagrid and I'm using dataset to do it. Now I have succeed to load xml file data to datagrid, the code as follows:

```
public class StoreDbDataSet
{
    internal static DataSet ReadDataSet()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXmlSchema("store.xsd");
        ds.ReadXml("store.xml");
        return ds;
    }

}
```

And:

```
public class StoreDb
{
    public ObservableCollection<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        DataSet ds = StoreDbDataSet.ReadDataSet();

        ObservableCollection<Product> products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        foreach (DataRow productRow in ds.Tables["Products"].Rows)
        {
            products.Add(new Product((string)productRow["ModelNumber"],
                (string)productRow["ModelName"], (string)productRow["InputAddress"],
                (string)productRow["OutputAddress"], (string)productRow["DiagAddress"],
                (string)productRow["Description"], (byte)productRow["CategoryID"],
                (string)productRow["CategoryName"], (string)productRow["ProductImage"]));
        }
        return products;
    }
}
```

Xaml File:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgBasicInfo" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsView, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserResizeColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,10,10,15" BorderThickness="5" FontSize="14" Background="White">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="SlaveId" Binding="{Binding CategoryID}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="ModelName" Binding="{Binding ModelName}"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="CategoryName" Binding="{Binding CategoryName}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="InputAddress" Binding="{Binding InputAddress}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="OutputAddress" Binding="{Binding OutputAddress}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="DiagAddress" Binding="{Binding DiagAddress}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Specification" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The ViewModel:

```
    public ICollectionView ProductsView
    {
        get { return _ProductsView; }
        set
        {
            _ProductsView = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

My question is when I changed the datagrid data, how can I save the changes to xml?Thanks in advance!

---------------------------update-------------------------------

```
    private void RefreshProductList()
    {
        ProductsView = new ListCollectionView(sdb.GetProducts())
        {
            Filter = obj =>
            {
                var Product = (Product)obj;
                return SelectedProduct != null && Product.ModelNumber == SelectedProduct.ModelNumber;
            }
        };
    }

    private Product selectedProduct;
    public Product SelectedProduct
    {

        get { return selectedProduct; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedProduct != value)
            {
                selectedProduct = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                RefreshProductList();
                RefreshModule();
                RefreshCommunication();
                List<Product> productlist = ProductsView.ToList();
                File.WriteAllText("store.xml", productlist.ToXML());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about [WriteXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I did that, but it just creat a new empty xml file.

Comment: which component that you writes to xml?
you are binding your data to ProductsView, 
see the changes on the setter method there.
if it is changed, then writes it to XML.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the correct code.

Comment: It seems that when I changed the data in the datagrid, System didn't call NotifyPropertyChanged in the ProductView method

Comment: @Grand Julivan I add a button click event to save changes to xml, as i mentioned it just creat a new empty xml file at the destination path.

Comment: you need to make sure your class implements the BindableBase , or Screen, or anything that could notify the propertychanged, and the ProductsView as well, have to implement the notify property changed.
you could start by also posting your "ProductsView" class here

Comment: @Grand Julivan The ProductsView did notify property changed, but just write a new xml file instead of update the data inside

Comment: Put changes back into the DataSet.  The rows and columns indexes of the DGV are the same as the DataTables in the DataSet.

Comment: @jdweng I use `WriteXml` method but just create a new xml file, why did this happen?

Comment: Don't understand question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are reading xml as a dataset instead read it as product and save it as array of product as below

Your xml format should look like this

```
<ArrayOfProduct>
<Product>
<ModelNumber>abc</ModelNumber>
//remaking properties 
</Product>
</ArrayOfProduct>
```

Create an extension method class, this help you convert xml to list vice versa

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts given class to XML using xml serialization
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of Class</typeparam>
    /// <param name="classObject">Class to be serialized</param>
    /// <returns>Xml string</returns>
    public static string ToXML<T>(this T classObject) where T : class
    {
        XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.IndentChars = "\t";
            settings.NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine;
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(ms, settings))
            {
                xmls.Serialize(writer, classObject);
            }

            string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            return xml;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts given XML string to class of type T
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type to be converted</typeparam>
    /// <param name="XmlData">xml string</param>
    /// <returns>class of Type T</returns>
    public static T ToClass<T>(this string XmlData)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        T newClass;
        using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(XmlData)))
        {
            //reader.Namespaces = false;
            newClass = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return newClass;
    }
}
```

Now your store db should look like this

```
public class StoreDb
{
    public ObservableCollection<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        string StoreData = string.Empty;
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("store.xml"))
          {
              StoreData = sr.ReadToEnd();
          }
        ObservableCollection<Product> products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(StoreData.ToClass<List<Product>());

        return products;
    }
}
```

Change productsView to observablecollection

```
private ObservableCollection<Product> _ProductsView;
public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductsView
    {
        get { return _ProductsView; }
        set
        {
            _ProductsView = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Now after your changes save xml as below

```
File.WriteAllText("store.xml",ProductsView.ToList().ToXml());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply,  but I got error when I try to load the xml data by your code.`InvalidOperationException: <NewDataSet xmlns=''> was not expected.
` 
my xml file looks like:
`<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Product>
  <ModelName>
  ....
`

Comment: I have given you xml format try to save your xml like that

Comment: I can't see difference between this two xml files

Comment: NewDataset can't be list<product>, if you serialize list<product> you will get root tag as ArraOfProduct

Comment: I changed it completely same to yours, still got error:
`InvalidOperationException: <ArraOfProduct xmlns=''> was not expected.
`

Comment: My mistake I missed y in Array check

Comment: My ProductsView inheritted from `ICollectionView` which don't have `ToList()` method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167752/is-there-a-way-to-convert-an-observable-collection-to-regular-collection

Comment: sorry to borther you, but I still get error when I tried 
`List<Product> productlist = ProductsView.ToList();`

Comment: error：`'ICollectionView' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollectionView' could be found`

Comment: Import  System.Linq at the top

Comment: That shold work, you are using ObservableCollection right ?

Comment: I believe so, that code works fine before I changed to your suggestions

Comment: change productsview to ObservableCollection

Comment: It seems that this code still cannot save changes to xml.This is link:[github link](https://github.com/Baaaaaarry/PX1_Configurator) I would appreciate it a lot if you could be kind helping me see what the problem is, I am really freaking out.

Comment: it's better you show me your problem Join in the meeting and show me https://meetings.webex.com/collabs/meetings/join?uuid=M5NZPM9RDCE9625EPSNFMBKWJG-4O2

Comment: could you tell me how to change the **-----update-----** after I change the `ListCollectionView` to `ObservableCollectionView` when It gave me the error:`ObservableCollectionView<Product> doesn't contain a definition for 'Filter' `

Comment: What's that filter for ?

Comment: Show the selected item from listbox to datagrid

Comment: For that you just create another property named selected product and bind it

Comment: Could you please tell me how to rewrite the `RefreshProductList` according to the **update** above, thanks very  very much!